# VBA - Do not insert row if columns are filtered

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to only allow a new row to be inserted as long as not columns E & F have not been filtered.

```
Sub addNewRow()
    
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Combination").Unprotect ("password")
    
    ' Do not insert a row before the first row.
    Const TopRow As Long = 10
    
    ' Get the active row number.
    Dim rowNum As Long
    rowNum = ActiveCell.Row
         
            
    If (rowNum > TopRow) And Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(5).On And Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(6).On Then

        Rows(rowNum).Insert       ' Insert a new row.
              
        Set CurRowR1 = Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(-1)
        Set NewRowR1 = Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row)
        CurRowR1.Copy
        NewRowR1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        NewRowR1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Set CurRowR2 = Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row & ":V" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(-1)
        Set NewRowR2 = Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row & ":V" & ActiveCell.Row)
        CurRowR2.Copy
        NewRowR2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        NewRowR2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Set CurRowR3 = Range("X" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AI" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(-1)
        Set NewRowR3 = Range("X" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AI" & ActiveCell.Row)
        CurRowR3.Copy
        NewRowR3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        NewRowR3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
       Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        
        ' === add a Check Box ===
        Dim oCB As CheckBox
        Dim c   As Range
        
        Set c = Cells(rowNum, 19)
        With c
            Set oCB = CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
            oCB.Caption = vbNullString
            oCB.Display3DShading = True
            oCB.Width = 18.29
            oCB.Height = 14.89
        End With
        
    Else: MsgBox ("Cannot insert new row while either 'Pneu. Cabinet' or Valve Node' Columns are filtered")
        
    End If
    
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Combination").Protect ("password"), AllowFiltering:=True

    
End Sub
```

However I'm getting Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range for

```
If (rowNum > TopRow) And Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(5).On And Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(6).On Then
```

I've tried to specify the sheet name rather than use ActiveSheet, but same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend you use a worksheet variable, e.g. `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Combination")`. Also, I think that you can't insert rows into a filtered range successfully so you could restrict the insertion to a not filtered worksheet with `If Not ws.FilterMode Then` and continue with `If rowNum > TopRow Then` since it is not appropriate to put these so different conditions in one line. Instead of `ActiveCell`, using `Selection`, and referencing it with a variable may be safer. Please share more details and screenshots of your data by editing your post.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh thanks for the tip to use .FilterMode, that's what I needed.
Changed to this and now a new row can be inserted using a linked form control button so long as the sheet has not been filtered, which is what I wanted.
The rest of the script copies down formulas and formatting from the row above and adds a check box to column S (19th across).
The form control button used to insert new row also runs a script to re-link all the checkboxes in column S to cells in the same row in another column too.

If the sheet has been filtered and there is an attempt to insert a new row, a message box to say "can't be done..." then exits sub

```
Sub addNewRow()
        
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Combination").Unprotect ("password")
        
        ' Do not insert a row before the first row.
        Const TopRow As Long = 10
        
        ' Get the active row number.
        Dim rowNum As Long
        rowNum = ActiveCell.Row
        
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Combination")
        
        
        If ws.FilterMode Then
        MsgBox "Cannot insert new row while either 'Pneu. Cabinet' or 'Valve Node' columns are filtered. This would result in formatting and formula errors." & vbCrLf & "Please clear filter before inserting new row"
                
        ElseIf (rowNum > TopRow) Then
       
            Rows(rowNum).Insert       ' Insert a new row.
                  
            Set CurRowR1 = Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(-1)
            Set NewRowR1 = Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row)
            CurRowR1.Copy
            NewRowR1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            NewRowR1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
            Set CurRowR2 = Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row & ":V" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(-1)
            Set NewRowR2 = Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row & ":V" & ActiveCell.Row)
            CurRowR2.Copy
            NewRowR2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            NewRowR2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
            Set CurRowR3 = Range("X" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AI" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(-1)
            Set NewRowR3 = Range("X" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AI" & ActiveCell.Row)
            CurRowR3.Copy
            NewRowR3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            NewRowR3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
           Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
           
            
            ' === add a Check Box ===
            Dim oCB As CheckBox
            Dim c   As Range
            
            Set c = Cells(rowNum, 19)
            With c
                Set oCB = CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
                oCB.Caption = vbNullString
                oCB.Display3DShading = True
                oCB.Width = 18.29
                oCB.Height = 14.89
            End With
        
                
        End If
        
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Combination").Protect ("password"), AllowFiltering:=True
        
    End Sub
```